# Issue with exception Block and yield function

Tags: python, cs50

I am trying to implement one program where user provides inputs(items) from a menu and in result we should get the total of those items(using dictionary for that). This is the  Felipe’s Taqueria CS50P question.

I wrote the code like this:

```
def main():
    dict = {
    "Baja Taco": 4.00,
    "Burrito": 7.50,
    "Bowl": 8.50,
    "Nachos": 11.00,
    "Quesadilla": 8.50,
    "Super Burrito": 8.50,
    "Super Quesadilla": 9.50,
    "Taco": 3.00,
    "Tortilla Salad": 8.00
    }
    sum = 0
    items = get_input()
    for item in items:
        if item in dict:
            sum = sum + dict[item]
            print("Total: $%.2f"% sum,sep="")
    print("Total: $%.2f"% sum,sep="")

def get_input():
    while True:
        try:
            n = input("Item: ").lower().title()
            yield n
        except EOFError:
             print()
             break

    return n




if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I am able to run this code perfectly, but there is some issue while uploading this to CS50.
Error: :( input of EOF halts program
expected exit code 0, not 1

Can someone explain me about this issue?

Comment: Don't use `dict` as a variable name, as it is a function to create dictionaries: `dict(name="fun")` is the same as `{"name": "fun"}`

Comment: @WOWOW - I did the change you mentioned, but that is not resolving the error I am getting.

Comment: It was also just a side note, not the answer to your question

Comment: That is why I didn't post it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to understand why you get exit code 1. You created a generator that calls function `get_input()`. This function raises an `EOFError` when the user types `Ctrl+D`. That error/exception is raised back to `main()`, but not handled there. As a result, your program exits with that error code.

To resolve that behavior, you need a `try/except` in `main()` to handle the raised `EOFError`. There are 2 ways to do this: 1) rearrange your code so the `try/except` around the `input()` block is in `main()`, or 2) add a 2nd `try/except` in `main()` to handle exceptions from the generator. I prefer the 1st method because it is simpler and does not require 2 try/except blocks. (IMHO a 2nd `try/except` for the generator is overly complicated.)

As an aside, @WOWOW is correct; `dict` is a Python reserved keyword. This does not create an error, but it would be better to use a different name for that variable (say `price_dict`).

Comment: Thanks very much for your response and it is very insightful. I tried with the simpler approach and it worked.

Comment: Glad that  helped. If it solved your problem, please click on the check mark to accept so others know when they read this in the future. Regards.